# Assert a generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I want to assert function taking a generic type will return that type so that it is no longer of type `JSONSchemaType<any>` but it is now for example of type `JSONSchemaType<Foo>`.

Console logged schema should be of type `JSONSchemaType<Foo>` and req.body of type `Foo`.

I cannot get past resolve the `any` to an actual type I will be passing over as the `schema` argument.

```js
import express from "express";
import { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";

type SchemaAssertionHandler<
  S extends JSONSchemaType<any>
> = express.RequestHandler<
  unknown,
  unknown,
  S extends JSONSchemaType<infer B> ? B : never
>;

export function doesRequestConformTo<S extends JSONSchemaType<any>>(
  schema: S
): SchemaAssertionHandler<S> {
  return (
    req: express.Request<unknown, unknown, unknown>,
    _unused: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
  ) => {
    console.log(schema);
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
  };
}
```

```js
interface Foo {
  bar?: string;
};

const fooSchema: JSONSchemaType<Foo> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    bar: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
  },
};
doesRequestConformTo(fooSchema);
```

The warning:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'JSONSchemaType<Foo>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSONSchemaType<any>'.
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/express-typescript-example-forked-jql02t?file=/src/validation.ts)

Comment: When I open that sandbox, I get much more basic errors, like *"Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'."* on the first `unknown` type argument you're passing `express.RequestHandler`. Separately, the question doesn't seem to show any attempt to create an assertion function to do what you're describing.

Comment: What you appear to be trying to do is coerce a type via a generic (all done statically) and expect that you have a different outcome at runtime.  The object is still what it is at runtime.  Remember the runtime doesn't know about your types, beyond how they were constructed.  Type guards or predicates will allow your code to syntactically deal with narrower types, but it doesn't change the actual type created at runtime.  `console.log` knows nothing of your types/interfaces, although will be able to show the constructor used.

Comment: @DaveMeehan but all I want it to assert is what it already has, access to a generic which is always passed as an argument into JSONSchemaType. I thought TypeScript could at least work that out by having access to `schema: S`

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk It's really not easy to tell from your code what you are trying to achieve.  You function name appears to be asking a question (does) but is then returning an unrelated type.  As written, you know it conforms to `JSONSchemaType`, but I suspect you want to know if its a `Foo` schema.  Perhaps you can restate your question to clarify?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXKEoW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.